# Crypto++ SelfTestFailure exception - cannot use any library code

Tags: c++, crypto++

In my C++ aplication I'd like to use Crypto++ library.
After hours of trying to successfully build project, when I finally managed to do so, I encountered this exception when running application:

"Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE59DF9709 in Przychodnia.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CryptoPP::SelfTestFailure at memory location 0x0000007BEEAFF210.".

I have tried using SHA, SHA3, AES, and all of those tries resulted with the same exception mentioned above.

Code that i try to execute:

```
        CryptoPP::AES hash;
        CryptoPP::byte key[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH], iv[CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE];
        memset(key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
        memset(iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
        //above code works fine
        //code below results in exception
        std::string output;
        CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
        CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);
```

Call stack:

```
KernelBase.dll!00007ffe59df9709()
vcruntime140d.dll!00007ffe2f69b230()
cryptopp.dll!CryptoPP::Algorithm::Algorithm(bool checkSelfTestStatus)
[External Code] 
Przychodnia.exe!CryptoPP::BlockCipherFinal<0,CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc>::BlockCipherFinal<0,CryptoPP::Rijndael::Enc>(const unsigned char * key, unsigned __int64 length)
Przychodnia.exe!Encryptor::encode(const std::string& password)
Przychodnia.exe!main() 
[External Code]
```

It is possible, that I have done something wrong when compiling cryptlib from crypttest.sln, linking and copying .lib and .dll files, but I'm not even sure what and where to look for. I will provide any necessary details if needed.

Comment: It seems likely that you have done something wrong since the built library is failing it's own internal tests. Why did the build take hours, what kind of difficulties did you have. Maybe there is a clue there.

Comment: I always worry when people copy lib files. The way to handle that is to tell the linker where the lib files are instead of copying them to where you think they should go. Copying them is just asking for trouble because inevitably you end up with two copies which may not be in sync.